# Java advanced image manipulation

Tags: java, image, 3d

I am having a problem with manipulating images in java 7. I have researched the problem I am having for three weeks and have failed to find a solution,

I am trying to set an image over an area, basically setting the corner posistions.
I am using a BufferedImage.

This is for a 3D game where I am writing the 3D conversion code. I have managed to create a 3d world, and populate it with cubes, filling in the sides with graphics.fillPolygon():

What I would like to do is draw an image that fills a polygon's shape.

Any help I will be grateful for (even if it is formating this post better).

Comment: What 3d framework are you using?

Comment: He says he is writing the conversion code. So I guess no framework.

Comment: The post is very vague... I doubt that somebody can help without telling more exactly what you want to do, what you're using, what you have tried...

Comment: He is using `graphics.fillPolygon()`, so there is no 3D enginge, he just paints on a swing component or so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use transformations on your graphics. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html) is a little tutorial on it. With that you can transform already drawn stuff. If you want to transform multiple images in different ways, you can draw them on different canvases and transform then separately. Then you can merge the images together...

But I would recommend using a 3D engine (JOGL, jMonkeyEngine, or others) for that (unless you want to learn about the geometric calculations with this task). It is also much faster to use OpenGL than drawing the stuff by yourself and doing the calculations in code (most probably meaning: on the CPU and not the GPU).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the  [drawImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29)? instead of `.fillPolygon`?

Comment: What I would like to do is draw an image that fills a polygon's shape, not just an image. Thanks for the help though.